# Importing Multivalue DB with SSIS into SQL

Tags: sql, ssis, multivalue

I would like to know if it is possible to Transfer Data into SQL Server from a multi value database file using SSIS.

The only thing that I could find online was using a bluefinity tool to achieve this.

Thanks
Simona

Comment: Multi-value database file?  As in what, the output from an EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) table?  Or some sort of (perhaps large) CSV?  SQL Server should have an `import` command...

Comment: Is there a specific Multivalue database that you are using?  Bluefinity seems like a viable solution, but it would be helpful if you could specify the exact product you are using for the source database.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this from Universe, but Universe has an ODBC driver that allows the datavase to be viewed as if they were tables. Almost like SQL views.

SSIS can import from almost anything that you can get either a .Net, ODBC, or OLE DB driver for. There has to be someway to talk to the DB from an extrnal program, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you has no driver (ODBC,OLEDB,.NET). So you can use C# script (even from SSIS) and extract data to flat file and then to SQL Server or do it directly to SQL Server.